# Javascript to execute after python function in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

Am new to coding and learning Python. Currently working on Flask to make some webapp. For one of the project I am trying to achieve the below

(1) On a webpage , I have a button when clicked, I pass the values inside the textbox to Python  function. Which does some operation of getting the data from the database and it create an html which stores that database query output into a table.
(2) When this HTML file is generated with the table inside, I want to display the same in my webpage in an iframe (the page generates iframe automatically)

The way I have achieved this is  having 2 buttons, One button to pass the values to Python function and second button to display the generated HTML into an iframe.

```
<br />
<input type='submit' value='Process Query' class="savebtn" name='Submit' />
<br /> 
<input type='button' value='Submit Query' class="savebtn" name='Submit' onclick="myFunction()" />

. . .

<script>

function myFunction() {

   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   $('iframe').not(this).remove();
   var html = '

   <body>Foo</body>';
   iframe.src = 'http://192.xx.xx.xx:10000/Table.html';
   iframe.height = "500";
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   console.log('iframe.contentWindow =', iframe.contentWindow);

}
</script>
```

I think the second button is unnecessary but am not sure how can I do this?

Apologies if this is found too basic for many but as i said , am starting to learn coding.

Comment: Post your server side code that doesn't work as you'd like to so people can understand how to create an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you want is to first process the text and generate some html, and then display this same html to a user. If that is the case, what you need is an [asynchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

With an asynchronous request, you send data off to the server (without reloading the web page) and when you receive a response, you do something with it. A very crude code would be something like

```
    function clickButton(){
        fetch("/<path_to_server>/")

        .then(function(result) { // This is the response from the server
           return result.json(); // convert it to json
         })

         .then(function(data) {
           // process your returned data 
           // e.g. data.generated_table could be your html output
           // which you can now display in your iframe
         })
    }
```