# Flask - use of two buttons with two different aims

Tags: python, html, flask, button

I am creating a flask app in order to manage a motor.
What I would like to do is to click on one button to start the motor and to click on another one to stop the movement of the motor.

However, I don't know how to differentiate the role of my two buttons.

It will be easier if I show you what I have done so far.

Here my `main.py` (in a simplified version):

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template
import canopen
from canopen import node
from libs.DriveLib import Drive
from libs.CookingStationLib import CookingStation
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
from canopen.profiles.p402 import BaseNode402
# os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 down")
# os.system("sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000")
# os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 up")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/cooking_station/')
def home_cooking_station():
    return render_template('cooking_station.html')

@app.route('/cooking_station/', endpoint='cooking_station', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test_endurance_cooking_station():
    # print('solid>>>>>>', nodeid_solid)
    return testing('cooking_station.html', 'cooking_station', 'cooking_station-test-')

def testing(template_file, silo_type, name):

    global motor_id
    global object_controlword 
    # object_controlword = 0x6040
    global object_statusword 
    # object_statusword = 0x6041
    global angle
    global speed
    global move
    global distance
    global timing
    global power_level

    speed = request.form['speed']
    move = request.form['move']

    if request.form.get("submit"):
        speed = request.form['speed'] 
        move = request.form['move'] 
    print("MOVE", move)
    if speed  == '':
        speed = 0
    if move  == '':
        move = 0
    
    now = datetime.now()
    python_file = open(name + now.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H:%M:%S") + ".txt", "x")

    if silo_type == 'cooking_station':
        CookingStation1 = CookingStation(int(51), int(3))
        timing = request.form['timing']
        power_level = request.form['power_level']
        if request.form.get("submit"):
            timing = request.form['timing']
            power_level = request.form['power_level']
        if timing  == '':
            timing = 0
        if power_level  == '':
            power_level = 0
        angle = int(speed) * int(timing)
        message2=angle
        print("Move: ", move)
        print("angle: ", message2)

        if int(move) == 1:
            CookingStation1.Drive.move_home()
        if int(move) == 5:
            CookingStation1.Drive.move_rel(int(angle), int(speed))
            CookingStation1.InductionGenerator.setPower(int(power_level))
            CookingStation1.InductionGenerator.enable(int(timing))
            message = ""
    
        # if request.form.get("stop"):
        # if request.form.action == 'STOP':
        if request.form.get('stop'):
            print("stop test")
            CookingStation1.InductionGenerator.disable()
            message = "The induction generator has stopped !"
        python_file.write("Execution date and time: " + now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S") + ", Angle chosen: " + str(angle) + ", Speed chosen: " + str(speed) + ", Power value: " + str(power_level) + '\n')
        return render_template(template_file, angle=angle,speed=speed,move=move,timing=timing,power_level=power_level,message2=message2, message=message)
```

And my `cooking_station.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/main.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{
        url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){
          // BASIC
          numpad.attach({target: "demoA"});
          // WITH OPTIONS
          numpad.attach({target: "demoB"});
          numpad.attach({target: "demoC"});
        });
    </script>

    <title>Rotation for the cooking station</title>
    <p class="title"><strong>TEST THE ROTATION FOR THE COOKING STATION</strong></p>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="onglets">
            <li><a href="/solid_silos/"> Solid Silos </a></li>
            <li><a href="/liquid_silos/"> Liquid Silos </a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/cooking_station/"> Cooking Station </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="special_td">
                    
                    <form>
                        <table>
                            <p2>Different callable functions:</p2><br>
                            <p1> ★ Motor come back to initial position</p1> <br>
                            <p1> ★ Motor moves relative </p1><br>
                            <p1> ★ Motor moves absolute </p1>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="special_td">
                    <!--test form-->
                    <form method="post" action="/cooking_station/">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="special_td">
                                    <table> 
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td> <p>Function:</p> </td> 
                                            <td><select name="move" method="GET" action="/cooking_station/" style="height:50px;">
                                                <option value= "1" name="3" >Home swing</option>
                                                <option value= "5" name="5" >Relative</option>
                                                <option value= "5" name="2" SELECTED>★★★★</option>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td> <p>Power level:</p> </td> 
                                            <td> <input type="text" name="power_level" id="demoA" style="height:50px;" value={{power_level}}> </td> 
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td> <p>Velocity:</p> </td> 
                                            <td> <input type="text" name="speed" id="demoB" style="height:50px;" value={{speed}}> </td> 
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td> <p>Timer:</p> </td> 
                                            <td> <input type="text" name="timing" id="demoC" style="height:50px;" value={{timing}}></td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td> <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"> </td> 
                                            <td><p3>{{message}}</p3></td>
                                            <td><p3>The angle is: {{message2}} grad</p3></td>
                                        </tr> 
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <tr> 
                        <td> <input type="button" id="submit" name="stop" class="stop" value="stop"> </td> 
                        <td><p3>{{message}}</p3></td>
                    </tr> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working well when I clicking the `Submit` button but it is not working when I am calling the `stop` button and I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

1. A `submit` button has to be part of a form and clicking it submits the form (no extra code is required).This is why your `submit` works.

2. Your `stop` button is not a `submit` button. This means you need Javascript code to make it do something when user clicks on it. You did not show any javascript code so I assume you don't have one. Essentially you have to trigger a function when user clicks on the button and the function will then make a call to your server to execute the stop action that you want.

***Updates based on comments from OP ***

1. You could make an ajax/asynchronous call. See sample code I provided in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666142/15211203). Note it's rough code and was provided as a guideline
2. You can also use 2 submit buttons in your form where the `stop` submit button will go to a different url. See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/separate-form-submit-buttons-go-different-urls/) (the last section) on how to do this

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I do it like that `<input type="button" id="submit" name="stop" class="stop" value="stop" onclick="disable();">` then from javascript how can I call my python/flask function?